# How to run a specific function if the component has been called by a specific component and not by other components in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component called **select-diagnosis** which is used by many different components.
When **select-diagnosis** is called by a specific component called **PtdTreatment**, it needs to run a specific function inside the fetchDiagnosis function, while when called by other components it will not run that specific function.

The fetchDiagnosis needs to understand that **select-diagnosis** component has been called by the **PtdTreatment** component.

How to do something like that?

This is the code from **PtdTreatment** component:

```
<el-form-item
    label="diagnosis"
    prop="dimission_diagnosis"
    v-if="form.data_dimission">
        <select-diagnosis
            v-model="form.diagnosis_dimission"
            :defaultValue="_.get(record, 'clean_diagnosis_dimission')"
        />
</el-form-item>
```

And this is the **select-diagnosis** component:

```
<template>
    <el-select
        v-bind="$attrs"
        :value="value"
        @change="onChange"
        @clear="onClear"
        clearable
        filterable
        remote
        :remote-method="fetchDiagnosis"
        :loading="loadingSelect"
    >
        <el-option
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="`diagnosis-${item.id}`"
            :label="item.code + ' - ' + item.description"
            :value="item.code"
        >
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "SelectDiagnosis",
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: ["value", "defaultValue"],
    data() {
        return {
            loadingSelect: false,
            items: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fetchDiagnosis(query) {
            const valid = query !== "" && query.length > 2;
            if (!valid) return;
            this.loadingSelect = true;
            let params = { string: query };
            axios
                .get("/config/diagnosi", { params })
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    //pseudo code
                    // if this component is called by **select-diagnosis** then do this
                      this.items = data.filter(diagnosi => {
                          const code = diagnosi.codice.replace(/\b0+/g, "");
                          if (code.length >= 4) {
                              return diagnosi;
                          }
                      });
                    // else do this
                       this.items = data;
                })
                .finally(() => (this.loadingSelect = false));
        },
        onChange(x) {
            this.$emit("input", x);
        },
        onClear() {
            this.$emit("input", null);
            this.items = [];
        }
    },
    watch: {
        defaultValue: {
            immediate: true,
            handler(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal && oldVal === undefined) {
                    this.items = [newVal];
                    this.$emit("input", newVal.codice);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't read your code, but your question alone creates a huge design smell. Components are meant to encapsulate what they are and do, they should never be aware of, let alone reliant on, their context. If your component must be able to do things differently based on a condition, introduce a prop that allows configuring it to these needs.

Comment: @connexo is correct here, which is why I think the inversion of control pattern is a good idea in this case. Rather than the `select-diagnosis` function caring at all which parent called it, it merely exposes an API for any parent component to use to filter its data in any way the parent likes. You could have another component `XyzTreatment` later on that needs a different way to filter, and rather than rewrite the child component to allow for the new feature, the API is already there in the child to hook into the fetch function and filter any way the parent would like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, the two that come to mind immediately use props.

1. You could pass a `filterDiagnoses` boolean prop to select-diagnosis. If it's true, run the filter logic.

```
<select-diagnosis v-model="form.diagnosis_dimission" :defaultValue="_.get(record, 'clean_diagnosis_dimission')" :filterDiagnoses="true" />
```

2. You could invert control to the parent function and expose a `filterFn` callback prop - the parent function passes a function prop to the child that the child will call upon fetching the diagnoses (this feels cleaner and more extensible):

```
/* in the PtdTreatment component */
/* ... */
methods: {
  filterDiagnosis(data) {
    // filter data
  },
}

/* in the PtdTreatment template */
<select-diagnosis v-model="form.diagnosis_dimission" :defaultValue="_.get(record, 'clean_diagnosis_dimission')" :filterFn="filterDiagnosis" />

/* in the select-diagnosis component */
fetchDiagnosis(query) {
  const valid = query !== "" && query.length > 2;
  if (!valid) return;
  this.loadingSelect = true;
  let params = { string: query };
  axios
    .get("/config/diagnosis", { params })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      if (this.filterFn) {
        this.items = this.filterFn(data);
      } else {
        this.items = data;
      }
    })
    .finally(() => (this.loadingSelect = false));
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `prop` on the child component which specifies the 'identity' of the parent component, then test for that in the child:

```
<select-diagnosis
  v-model="form.diagnosis_dimission"
  :defaultValue="_.get(record, 'clean_diagnosis_dimission')"
  parent="PtdTreatment"
/>
```

Then in the child (simplified example):

```
export default {
    props: ["value", "defaultValue", "parent"],
    methods: {
        fetchDiagnosis(query) {
          if (this.parent === "PtdTreatment") {
            // Parent-specific code here
          }
        }
    }
}
```